# How could you define this variable?

Tags: terminology, experiment-design, priming

The procedure of one experiment includes the next sequence:

1. The anagram is presented for several seconds;
2. The "special word" is presented for 90 ms;
3. The same anagram is presented again;
4. The anagram is solved by the participant.

It is predicted that the "special word" from the item №2 influences the probability  of solving the anagram successfully.

How is it better to define the "special word"? It could be defined as prime, but priming per se implies that the stimulus precedes the target stimulus (e. g., anagram), and that is not the case here.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Isn't the target stimulus the second viewing of the anagram? In which case the "special word" would be the primer within the definition you provided.

Comment: *...[priming requires] the [primer to] precede[.] the target stimulus* - isn't that exactly the case? It's sandwiched, yes, but it still precedes the last 'real' stimulus. I think you answered your own question.

Comment: @AliceD, I agree with you. But the problem is that the target stimulus equals the first stimulus (the anagram is the same). Thus, the process of solving, which presumably should be influenced by the "prime", starts before the "prime" is presented.

Comment: Umum. What about facilitator? Pointer? Catalyst? Hint?

Comment: @AliceD, I thought about these alternatives too. Also I would add "cue" to your list. However, in some trials the "special word" is predicted to affect the solving process negatively. That is why I am trying to come up with a neutral term.